# Mysterious ESLint Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

On line 4 of the following code, ESLint is giving me a parsing error saying:

> Unexpected token =

I'm wondering why this is the case? The code runs properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class MainApp extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.any.isRequired
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    require('./styles/main.styl');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have properties inside classes, you can only have methods.

Reference: http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#inside_the_body_of_a_class_definition

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! I'm new to ES6 classes.

Comment: I'm using babel stage-0, which would allow this syntax. I'm using eslint-config-airbnb, and i want to add this rule to eslint. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do i use both babel-eslint and eslint-config-airbnb at the same time? I tried to config eslint to do this to no avail.

Comment: Just a note, class properties will be available from ES7 and there's already a babel-eslint module for them and of course transpilers.

Comment: Downvoting b/c this is no longer common practice; for example, `create-react-app` now includes the object properties syntax by default, and it is a common Babel include.  This answer was correct-ish at one time, but is now out of date.

Answer (score 19):

I was able to fix this by:

#### 1) Install babel-eslint

`$ npm i --save-dev babel-eslint`

OR

`$ yarn add babel-eslint --dev`

#### 2) Configure ESLint to use babel-eslint as your parser

Just add `"parser": "babel-eslint",` to your .eslintrc file.

Sample .eslintrc to use `babel-eslint` and airbnb's configuration with some custom rules:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "arrow-body-style": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-continue": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you added `"parser": "babel-eslint"` & still experience the same issue... make sure your .babelrc contains `"transform-class-properties"` inside plugins (make sure you add it first: `yarn add babel-plugin-transform-class-properties -D`)