# Disabling eslint for .ejs files

Tags: node.js, ejs, eslint, eslintrc, eslintignore

I have a template file on my project and while running the eslint I am facing various issues because of it. Some of those are -

`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token !`

`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token <`

To overcome from that I tried to use `eslint-plugin-ejs` with no help. I have visited below SO links as well -

[Turning off eslint rule for a specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764287/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-file)

[ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001552/eslint-parsing-error-unexpected-token)

[Mysterious ESLint Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125141/mysterious-eslint-parsing-error/34125219)

and many more but again with no luck. Now I just want this file to be excluded from eslint but couldn't find the way to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) says.

You can use of [inline configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) `/*eslint-disable*/` and `/*eslint-enable*/`.

---

[image]

---

**@EDIT** to what you've said in comment, there are two solutions

**1** You can use of the property `excludedFiles`, I've found an example in the documentation :

[image]

---

**2** You can handle the `HTML` and `EJS` files in a particular way as described [here](https://github.com/roadhump/SublimeLinter-eslint/issues/62)

**3** You can also use the `.eslintignore` file as described at [Ignoring Files and Directories](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)

Comment: The problem is `/**/` comments doesn't work in html or ejs file. so this option is not viable.

Comment: @Jeet I've done an edit, with two soluce answering your problem

Comment: 2nd options doesn't work still because there is no script tag in the file or no javascript processing. It is a plain ejs file, however the 1st options looks like it is working since I don't get the error anymore. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I'm honestly curious. Is "soluce" a real word, or did you mean "solutions"?

Comment: @MichaelDorst Indeed I mean *solutions*. Sorry about my english mistakes.

Comment: Of all the solutions, the `.eslintignore` one, number 3 in the list, worked well for me.